# noquote by default for QDebug created in QMessageLogger

Tags: qt, logging

I log errors using [`QLoggingCategory`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html) stuff. Every time I have to use `.noquote()`:

```
qCWaning(appCategory).noquote()
            << QCoreApplication::translate("app", "Unable to create object from URL %1")
               .arg(url.toString());
```

to disable `""` quotes inserted around message text.

Is it possible to make every instance of `QDebug` created by `QMessageLogger`'s methods to be `.noquote()` by default?

Surely I can make `#define`s for every kind of message category. But is there global settings for that?

Comment: Nothing AFAIK (up to 5.12.2), other than redefining macros or modifying the source code (`qdebug.h` should be enough).